# How to convert code written in batch file to shell script?

Tags: shell, batch-file

I have a code which is written in batch script that is to be converted to shell script.

`for /f "tokens=2" %%s in (%EC2_HOME%\Volumes.txt) do call ec2-create-snapshot %%s`

The content of volume.txt is

`ATTACHMENT vol-f6  i-2601  /dev/sda1   attached    2013-11-20T06:42:49+0000    true
ATTACHMENT  vol-3d3 i-e1d6  /dev/sda1   attached    2013-11-21T12:38:09+0000    true`

any lead is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert the following snippet of code written in batch file to shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468445/how-to-convert-the-following-snippet-of-code-written-in-batch-file-to-shell-scri)

Comment: What does your script do?  That is, what arguments do you want to pass to ec2-create-snapshot?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: the arguement is the `volume id` which is fetched from volume file. it is to be written for linux

Comment: What kind of shell script though? bash?

Comment: @qstebom: yeah i have to write this in shell script

Comment: But 'shell' script does not imply the interpreter. You mean Bourne shell?

Comment: @ i just know i have to execute this script on centos. i dont know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this:

```
while read BLAH VOL REST; do
  ec2-create-snapshot "$VOL"
done < "$EC2_HOME/Volumes.txt"
```

Comment: but how it will fetch the volume id?

Comment: @how will it fetch the 2nd column of the text file?

Comment: Try it!  I think it will.  :)

Comment: The filename is Volumes.txt, as in your example.  The `BLAH VOL REST` are variable names to read the first token, second token, and the rest of the line.

Comment: i want to read only the volume id that is the second column ? how to do that?

Comment: I don't use the BLAH and REST tokens, so I think that's what my script does.  Please just try it.  You can put `echo` in front of the ec2 command itself to just print before running it for real the first time, to confirm it does what you need.

Comment: it has gone to infinite loop

Comment: hey its working i have a script? could you please convert it into a shell script?

Comment: can  you tell me the syntax of `for` loop for the smae

Comment: It works as written for me.  It should work on most systems, including your CentOS.  You'll need to give a lot more detail if it's still not working, such as exactly how you are invoking it.

Comment: @ could you please convert my batch script to shell script. i will be very thankful to you !! :)

Comment: its giving an error : `Client.MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter volume`

Comment: Put "echo" in front of the ec2 command in the loop, run it, and tell us what it says.

Comment: when executed its giving this `ec2-create-snapshot vol-f0
ec2-create-snapshot` because the second create snapshot is not taking arguement that is why it is giving this error. please help in solving this error

Comment: actually my volume.text file has only one volume id

Comment: Does your script look exactly like mine does right now?  Please review it.  It shouldn't do what you're saying, but make sure you're using the current version in my answer.

Comment: @ i dont know whats going on :( please help me out